# Convert or Format data of Nested Arrays in JSON Objects to Nested JSON Objects in Typescript For Bind Kendo Grid

Tags: json, angular, typescript, kendo-grid, webapi

I have been trying to convert a data of Nested Arrays in JSON Objects to Nested JSON Objects in Typescript. This is return data from rest api as getting in typescript:

Nested array contains square brackets.

```
data={ "ID":29614,"Ratio":8,"UOM":"IN", "manufacturers": [{ "manufacturerName": "john", "categories": [{ "categoryName": "Beverage", "products": [{ "uid": "567", "productID": 130927, "name": "After Shocks Popping Candy 1.06"}] }] } , { "manufacturerName": "Dan", "categories": [{ "categoryName": "Organization", "products": [{ "uid": "65", "productID": 5656, "name": "After Shocks Popping Candy 2.06"}] }] } ] }


Format I need is:

data=[{ "ID":29614,"Ratio":8,"UOM":"IN", "manufacturers": { "manufacturerName": "john", "categories": { "categoryName": "Beverage", "products": { "uid": "567", "productID": 130927, "name": "After Shocks Popping Candy 1.06"} } } , { "manufacturerName": "Dan", "categories": { "categoryName": "Organization", "products": { "uid": "65", "productID": 5656, "name`enter code here`": "After Shocks Popping Candy 2.06"} } } }]

Output nested array should remove square brackets.

I have tried this as

public gridData: any[];
//gridData  for bind Kendo grid 

return this.restApi.getProductBin().subscribe((data: {}) => {
this.gridData = Array.of(data); //convert to array
}
```

Comment: this.gridData = typeof data === Array ? data : [data]

Comment: Kendo Grid binding UI format  as: <kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [height]="150" style="float:left;">
    <kendo-grid-column field="ID" title="ID" width="50">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="manufacturers.manufacturerName" title="manufacturerName" width="50">
    </kendo-grid-column>
  </kendo-grid>

Comment: This is a horribly written question. Kindly improve. You don't need good english, you simply need good formatting.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is remove the square brackets, you could stringify the JSON, use a regular expression to remove all '[' and ']', and then parse it back into a JSON object:

```
getNoArrayJSON(data: {}): {} {
    let dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
    dataString = dataString.replace(/(\[)|(\])/g, "");
    return JSON.parse(dataString);
});
```

I wouldn't do this unless you know that the arrays in the response you're dealing with will only ever have a size of 1.

Working Example: [RegEx Remove arrays](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jvhrbq)

If you're set on putting that result in an array, `let newData = [getNoArrayJSON(data)];` and the format will exactly match your desired output.

Comment: Could you please Format below data = {
 "ID":29614,"Ratio":8,"UOM":"IN",
  "manufacturers": [{
    "manufacturerName": "john",
    "categories": [{
      "categoryName": "Beverage",
      "products": [{ "uid": "567", "productID": 130927, "name": "After Shocks Popping Candy 1.06"}]
    }]
  }
    ,
    {
      "manufacturerName": "Dan",
      "categories": [{
        "categoryName": "Organization",
        "products": [{ "uid": "65", "productID": 5656, "name": "After Shocks Popping Candy 2.06"}]
      }]
      }

 ]
}   @David Fagerburg

Comment: Could you please help me to format of multiple size of data @David Fagerburg

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
  output = [];

  constructor() {
    this.output.push({
      ID: this.data.ID,
      Ratio: this.data.Ratio,
      UOM: this.data.UOM,
      manufacturers: {
        manufacturerName: this.data.manufacturers[0].manufacturerName,
        categories: {
          categoryName: this.data.manufacturers[0].categories[0].categoryName,
          products: this.data.manufacturers[0].categories[0].products[0]
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbjgbz?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: ,@MEDZ ,I there any way to remove Square brackets without mention array object names to use commonly.@Adrita Sharma

Comment: Could you plz help to this JSon data loop through,To remove square brackets.@Adrita Sharma